# Наложение background друг на друга

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делал parallax и scroll для платформера но столкнулся с проблемой наложения задних фонов друг на друга. Концепция такая, у меня 5 backround и в каждом находится свой слой, при движении персонажа левый фон перемещается вправо и наоборот. Однако что-то пошло не так и мой фон начинает накладываться друг на друга, тем самым уменьшая общий фон из 3 компонентов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске все нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако двигаясь в ту или иную сторону, начинается наложение и фон уменьшается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallax : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float backgroundSize;
    [SerializeField]
    private float parallaxSpeed;

    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private Transform[] layers;
    private float viewZone = 5;
    private int leftIndex;
    private int rightIndex;

    private float lastCameraX;

    private void Start()
    {
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        lastCameraX = cameraTransform.position.x;
        layers = new Transform[transform.childCount];

        for (int i=0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            layers[i] = transform.GetChild(i);
        }

        leftIndex = 0;
        rightIndex = layers.Length - 1;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float deltaX = cameraTransform.position.x - lastCameraX;
        transform.position += Vector3.right * (deltaX * parallaxSpeed);
        lastCameraX = cameraTransform.position.x;

        if (cameraTransform.position.x < (layers[leftIndex].transform.position.x + viewZone))
        {
            ScrollLeft();
        } 

        if (cameraTransform.position.x > (layers[rightIndex].transform.position.x - viewZone))
        {
            ScrollRight();
        }
    }

    private void ScrollLeft()
    {
        int lastRight = rightIndex;
        layers[rightIndex].position = Vector3.right * (layers[leftIndex].position.x - backgroundSize);
        leftIndex = rightIndex;
        rightIndex--;

        if (rightIndex < 0 )
        {
            rightIndex = layers.Length - 1;
        }
    } 

    private void ScrollRight()
    {
        int lastLeft = leftIndex;
        layers[leftIndex].position = Vector3.right * (layers[rightIndex].position.x + backgroundSize);
        rightIndex = leftIndex;
        leftIndex++;

        if (leftIndex == layers.Length)
        {
            leftIndex = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременно на экране может быть только 2 изображения, поэтому нет смысла в пяти картинках, нужны только 2 меняющие спрайты.

```
public class ScrollBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 1;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer[] _layers = new SpriteRenderer[2];
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] _images;
    private float _spriteWidth;
    private float _halfCameraWidth;
    private Transform _camera;
    private Transform[] _layersTransform;
    
    private void Start ()
    {
        _spriteWidth = _images[0].rect.width;
        Camera camera = Camera.main;
        _camera = camera.transform;
        float aspectRate = Screen.width/(float)Screen.height;
        _halfCameraWidth = camera.orthographicSize*aspectRate;
        _layersTransform = new Transform[_layers.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _layers.Length; i++)
            _layersTransform[i] = _layers[i].transform;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        float leftCameraBorder = _camera.position.x*_speed-_halfCameraWidth;
        int layersCount = Mathf.FloorToInt(leftCameraBorder/_spriteWidth);
        for (int i = 0; i < _layers.Length; i++) {
            Vector3 position = _layersTransform[i].localPosition;
            position.x = (layersCount+i+0.5f)*_spriteWidth;
            _layersTransform[i].localPosition = position;
        }
        int leftSpriteIndex = layersCount%_images.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _layers.Length; i++)
        {
            int spriteIndex = (leftSpriteIndex+i)%_images.Length;
            _layers[i].sprite = _images[spriteIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не может быть 3, 4, 5 изображений? Я не понимаю. Ведь фоновое изображение может быть из любого количества слоев(с прозрачностью, конечно же) которые просто двигаются с разной скоростью. И это тоже будет паралексом. Почему "дновременно на экране может быть только 2 изображения" ?

Comment: Я неправильно тебя понял. 2 изображения это не про паралакс, а про скролищейся бекграунд. Просто больше двух картинок скролищегося бекграунда одновременно не видно. Но я добавил код чтобы можно было менять скорость скролищегося слоя и из набора `ScrollBackground` с разными `Speed` можно сделать паралакс, но если это большие картинки из-за альфы это будет грузновато, лучше аппликации объектов.